# JSoup Extract Text by id

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to extract the text "Inbox (100)" html by id enclosed within  tags. My test case looks like this:

```
    String html = "<td id=\"e-mailoutline-row\" title=\"Inbox\" class=\"outline-text\">Inbox (100)</td>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element numberofEmails = doc.getElementById("e-mailoutline-row");
```

The issue is that numberofEmails is always null, so I can't even get the text, let alone work towards the actuall number in the brackets.

I also tried :

```
        String html = "<head><body><td id=\"e-mailoutline-row\" title=\"Inbox\" class=\"outline-text\">Inbox (100)</td></body?</head>";
```

Once I get the test case working I will use it to extract this text from a much larger document.

This should be simple. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably missing head and body, and you trying to parse as document, there is a way in jsoup to work with fragments.

Comment: @Yaroslav so it looks like its not happy that head and body are missing, but I did try that.

Comment: didn't mean to post link as answer -   https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup always follows hierarchy. In order parse from `td` tag it should come from `table->tr-->td`

```
 String html = "<head><body><table><tr><td id=\"e-mailoutline-row\">Inbox (100)</td></tr></table></body></head>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    Element numberofEmails = doc.getElementById("e-mailoutline-row");
    System.out.println(numberofEmails.text());
```

Output:

```
Inbox (100)
```

Comment: @soorapagman I should have mentioned that this test case will ultimately be used to extract that string from a much larger html document, so I don't want all doc.text - hence the extraction by id

Comment: I guess so.  it should get from Table ->tr-->td if you could share atleast that hierarchy i can help you out

Comment: Oops  downvoting with out proper reason ? what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the commands was correct, but it appears JSoup is picky about the html being correctly formed. The following html test case worked exactly as intended:

```
String html = "<head><body><table><tr><td id=\"e-mailoutline-row\">Inbox (100)</td></tr></table></body></head>";
```

Note I had to add not only  and  but  and  too. It did not work with head and body only added to the original test case.

Thanks to @soorapadman and @Yaroslav for pointing me in the right direction.